# How to copy and paste non English characters?

Tags: neovim, encoding

I'm using:

```
Neovim v0.4.4
Mac v10.13.6
iTerm2
```

When I copy non English text, for example `中文（简体）` and paste it to neovim, it become `????`

[image: vim issue]

The same thing happens to when I copy it from neovim and paste into any other place.

How can I fix this?

`set encoding` gives `encoding=utf-8`.

Comment: Does your locale and vim `encoding` option support these characters? That’s a likely culprit

Comment: I'm not sure, how can I check this?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, I included my `encoding` info into the description.

Comment: You should probably also check `:language` and `:!locale`, but knowing you're in utf-8 is a start. The next step is to find out if utf-8 supports those characters, and whether or not the exact ones you're coping are encoded in utf-8. Unfortunately, I'm not much help there.

Comment: Oh! I think it's something related to `tmux`, I'll check it

Comment: hey @D.BenKnoble, I fixed it by adding `export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8` and `export LANG="UTF-8"` into my `.zshrc`, but I'm not really sure what is it means.

Comment: I can't personally recommend putting code you don't understand in your dotfiles, but that's beside the point. Environment variables like `LC_ALL` and `LANG` (there are several others) control encoding assumptions, output formats, sort order, etc. of well-written programs. Generally the *correct* think to do is to configure your terminal emulator or system to set them appropriately. e.g., my Macbook is in French; when I launch Terminal.app, it sets all the variables automatically. But alacritty doesn't, so I have to add them to my alacritty config. (...)

Comment: (...) This way my shell files and other dotfiles stay somewhat "system-agnostic" (though I do tend to assume UTF-8 occasionally). Moral of the story: hard-coding locales is likely to break (same reason you shouldn't hardcode `TERM`)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115651/discussion-between-d-ben-knoble-and-lai32290).

Comment: Just FYI: Neovim always has `set encoding=utf-8` no matter what.

Comment: @Matt is that mean that I need to fix this issue in another way?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found the solution for this.

It was because of the locale setting of my terminal, so I exported these variables in my `.zshrc` (maybe you can put it into `.profile`, if you're not using `ZSH`).

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG="UTF-8"
```

Comment: Usually, setting `LC_ALL` should be avoided, since it's stronger than all the other `LC_*` settings and it will override them when they're used. (Many scripts use something like `LC_COLLATE=C sort` or similar and this `LC_ALL` setting will break them. Setting `LANG` is usually enough, but you should set it with a language and not only an encoding. `export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` is the correct setting here.

Comment: Many Linux distributions also support setting this in a `~/.i18n` file, without the `export` statement, only the `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` part. These distributions will have this setting work regardless of which shell is in use (bash, zsh, etc.)